# LazyInitializationException, for an int

Tags: java, hibernate, h2, lazy-initialization, proxy-classes

A simple class with an integer field:

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "myObject")
public class MyObject 
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @Column(columnDefinition = "int default 0")
  @Index(name = "refCount")
  private int refCount;

  public int getRefCount(){ return refCount; }
}
```

Objects are fetched from the database using a simple Utility method:

```
Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getCurrentSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

criteria.setFetchSize(1);
T object = (T) criteria.uniqueResult();

// I tried to add this line, but it made no difference
Hibernate.initialize(object);

tx.commit();
return object;
```

**The problem is the following:**
Shortly after fetching this object, I am calling the `getRefCount` method. At that point I encounter the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
    at mypackage.MyObject_$$_javassist_1.getRefCount(MyObject_$$_javassist_1.java)
```

My hibernate configuration file (i.e. `hibernate.cfg.xml`) contains the following property:

```
 <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

**What I don't understand:**
If this would happen to a collection, then I would just add the `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` annotation. But this simple `int` field is not a join. Why would an `int` ever be wrapped inside a `Proxy` in the first place ?

I tried to add the `Hibernate.initialize(object);` line, but it made no difference at all.

I also experimented with the `hibernate.current_session_context_class="managed"` setting. After which I had to start and stop all sessions manually. I opened it at every fetch and closed it in a finally block. But that also made no difference.

This is one of my first Hibernate projects. I'm starting to wonder if I should open a transaction before calling getters on hibernate objects.

I'm not using Spring, just Hibernate.

## EDIT: actually there is a 2nd object

Actually there is a parent object (which I initially thought was not important). This `Parent` object contains a link to the `MyObject`

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "parentObject")
public class ParentObject 
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  // link
  @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @ElementCollection(targetClass = MyObject.class)
  @JoinColumn(name = "myObjectId")
  private MyObject myObject;

  public MyObject getMyObject(){ return myObject; }
}
```

What happens is:

1. a `Parent` object gets fetched
2. `parent.getMyObject()` is called to get a `MyObject` instance
3. This `MyObject` instance is in fact a proxy without any fields on it.
4. As soon as I call a method on this `MyObject` instance, I get the `LazyInitializationException`

When I fetch my objects I make sure a session exists and a transaction is created. But after the fetching I immediately close the transaction.

I am not creating a transaction when I'm calling the `getMyObject()` or when calling the getters. I guess that's the problem. I'll test if that makes a difference.

## EDIT 2:

It turns out that I indeed need to call the getters inside a transaction. But that in itself is not enough.

A second problem is that the `Parent` object was fetched in a transaction that was already committed. As a result, the proxy object is no longer bound to an event. I guess that's what they call a "detached object". *(lol, I'm just learning as we go here.)*

**I had to "reattach" this object by calling the `Session#update(proxy)` method. Now finally I can call the getter without exceptions.**

```
// uses a transaction internally
Parent parent = MyHibernateUtil.fetch(Parent.class, ...);
MyObject object = parent.getMyObject();

...

// create a new transaction
Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getCurrentSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

// reattach the object
SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(myObject);

int count = myObject.getRefCount();
tx.commit();
```

But what I learned from this issue is that I probably use transactions the wrong way. I guess I should make longer transactions that contain both the fetches and the calls to the getters. Right ?

Comment: on sql level  refCount is an index ?

Comment: What is `criteria` in your code?

Comment: Try to invoke `getRefCount` instead of `initialize`

Comment: @ShadowRay hibernate created an index for this field, that's correct. This is a big-data database in fact. There are about 100M objects of `MyObect`. Each `MyObject` has multiple `Parent` objects. In reality there are multiple reference counters (e.g. `refCount`) which count how many parents they have with certain properties. The whole idea is to make a flat-record for `MyObject` (i.e. which contains precalculated data) which should make it easier to calculate complex statistics in a later phase.

Comment: >>But what I learned from this issue is that I probably 
>>use transactions the wrong way. I guess I should make longer 
>>transactions that contain both the fetches and the calls to the getters.
>>Right ?
No, in general you could call getters and setters of detached objects(for not lazy loaded fields, though).
But in your case all filelds are lazy loaded by some reason, and you can't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose whole object(MyObject in your case) is proxied. Could you call getId instead of getRefCount() ?

Comment: Try to use this annotation param:  @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(include = "non-lazy", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE);

Comment: the non-lazy, didn't help. I immediately tried it after you posted it. But in mean time did a retest and found out that I had to call `Session#update(myObject)`

Answer (score 1):

Try calling getId function before closing the transaction. Don't know what will happen but just a suggestion.